# ruby Input array into class

Tags: ruby

So I have an array (defined right away):

```
some_array = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

I am later declaring this class:

```
class Report
    def initialize(name)
        @name=name
     end
 end
```

I want to include the array into this class, so I can use the data. Can I import it like any other initialized data? So basically I have an array I want to use in a class.. every way I do it I'm getting undefined variables.

Comment: I'm going to loop through that array in the class, I'm not trying to input the array as arguments, but literally to loop through them inside the class.

Comment: Have you tried adding an argument to the `initialize` method and passing the array to that?

Answer (score 0):

`initialize` is called when creating an instance of a class. Try

```
some_array = ["a", "b", "c"]

class Report
  def initialize(name)
    @name=name
  end
end

# Create instance of Report:
report = Report.new some_array

# Check if instance variable @name has been set as expected:
report.instance_variable_get(:@name)
```

I hope you find this helpful.